# Automatically publish linked content from my social services on my blog

Tags: django, twitter, blogs, flickr, instagram

I'm looking into the possibility of having a blog similar to [Jeff Croft's](http://jeffcroft.com/), where the site automatically [queries its owner social services](http://jeffcroft.com/blog/2012/may/27/how-this-site-is-built/) (Twitter, Flickr, Pinboard, etc.) and publishes the content which links to the original service.

Is there a simple way to do this, or better yet, a blog engine that already implements something similar in a "plugable" manner? Ideally, a designer would be able to manage this on his own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Syte](http://rigoneri.github.com/syte/) does this for Twitter, Dribble, Tumbler, Github, Last.fm, and Instagram, and is a Django app built with responsive design.